# Desktop search combined with Intranet search

Tags: windows, search, intranet, desktop-search

I'm looking for a software similiar to Windows Desktop Search or Google Desktop, that can also display results from our Intranet search engine in the same manner it displays regular results (files/emails/etc.).

So far I managed to add Intranet search capabilities to Windows Desktop Search, but it doesn't show the results in the programs UI, but requires the user to press a "Search Intranet" button that opens the browser.

Would be happy to hear any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [X1](http://www.x1.com) and was very happy with its speed and its UI.

[image]

Comment: It's ok that the UI is nice but X1 doesn't support what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Lookeen](http://www.lookeen.net) as my designated search tool. Originally an Outlook search add-in, you can also set it up to index/search any folders you want. It's fast, pretty easy to use, and to customize. More information on it's website if you want...